# How to avoid triggering useEffect() from another useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, use-effect

I'm implementing pagination with React. It generally works well, except one issue.

When I'm changing sorting criteria, I want to reset page to 1st. The problem is, changing the page number triggers data fetch again. So whenever I'm on page 2 or above and change sorting criteria, the data is being fetched twice. Once for the fact of changing the criteria (which trigger resetting the page to 1) and then again, as the page changed to one. Is there any clean way to avoid this clash and make the fetch only happen once?

Here's my simplified code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [column, setColumn] = useState();
    const [direction, setDirection] = useState();
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);

    useEffect(
        () => (async () => {
            const response = await fetch('...');
            const { items } = await response.json();

            setItems(items);
        })(),
        [column, direction, currentPage, perPage]
    );

    useEffect(
        () => setCurrentPage(1), // This triggers the useEffect() above
        [column, direction, perPage]
    );

    return (
        // Template code
    );
}
```

How would a React guru do this?

Comment: doesn't it make sense to refetch when currentPage changes? Why do you want to stop that?

Comment: Because two useffect has same 3 dependencies. You can add only  sorting dependency to the second useeffect and remove from the first one

Comment: @RameshReddy sorry, I reworded my question a little bit. The problem is that it fetches twice.

Comment: As stated above, both useEffect depends on `direction`. first useEffect will trigger when direction changed, then will trigger again when currentPage changes. I would probably try having a `shouldFetch` state variable to determine if first useEffect needs to execute. And update the `shouldFetch` when it is needed to fetch.

Comment: @code90 I know why it happens, but how to structure it to make sense?

Comment: just updated my comment.. Can try the suggestion and provide some sample code later if you would still need it.

Comment: an easy way would be to remove the second `useEffect` and call `setCurrentPage` manually in the change handlers that update other states.

Comment: @RameshReddy are you sure that would be easy? `currentPage` needs to trigger `fetch()` when another page is clicked. And if I keep it as a dependency, it will fetch twice anyway.

Comment: @RoboRobok could you add a sandbox to the question? I'll fork and update that

Comment: @RameshReddy I prepared a working example, but not sure how to paste it. SO's snippets don't seem to handle JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a state like `shouldFetch` that can be used to conditionally fetch and avoid multiple calls.

[image: Edit nostalgic-williams-b4xfo]

```
  const [column, setColumn] = useState();
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (shouldFetch) {
        const response = await sleep(1000);
        console.log(response);

        // prevent fetch as we want to allow it later
        setShouldFetch(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [column, direction, currentPage, perPage, shouldFetch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentPage(1);
    // allow fetch
    setShouldFetch(true);
  }, [column, direction, perPage]);

  const changeColumn = () => {
    setColumn("new-col");
  };
  const changeCurrentPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage(2);

    // to fetch when currentPage changes
    // this should not be added to other handlers as it is also present in the second useEffect that gets triggered when other params change
    setShouldFetch(true);
  };
  const changePerPage = () => {
    setPerPage(20);
  };
  const changeDirection = () => {
    setDirection("descending");
  };
```

---

**Alternative:**

To avoid unnecessary fetching and to make sure that `items` are fetched using the updated state values, you can remove the second `useEffect` and reset `currentPage` when you update other params.

This will only trigger the `useEffect` once because React will perform both state updates (`setColumn` and `setCurrentPage`) at once.

[image: Edit dawn-sea-2rdif]

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res("Hi Mom"), ms));

export default function App() {
  // const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [column, setColumn] = useState();
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await sleep(1000);
      console.log(response);
    })();
  }, [column, direction, currentPage, perPage]);

  // remove this effect
  // useEffect(() => setCurrentPage(1), [column, direction, perPage]);

  const changeColumn = () => {
    setColumn("new-col");
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };
  const changeCurrentPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage(2);
  };
  const changePerPage = () => {
    setPerPage(20);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };
  const changeDirection = () => {
    setDirection("descending");
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={changeColumn}>change column</button>
      <button onClick={changeDirection}>change direction</button>
      <button onClick={changeCurrentPage}>change page</button>
      <button onClick={changePerPage}>change perPage</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a cleaner way? I have much more criteria than these presented here. Running `setCurrentPage(1)` every time looks bad.

Comment: However, it does fix the problem. I have a feeling that to make it cleaner, I'd need to use some sort of trick with `useRef()`.

Comment: @RoboRobok tried  `useRef` but it got uglier. Adding a new boolean state resulted in less code, check the updated answer.